# Base table or view not exist

Tags: magento2, product, database

I want to import product or create them via the BO.

Before, it's was OK, but, I don't know why, suddently, it's impossible to me to create product.

Each time, I got this error :

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'xxx.catalog_product_entity_Magento\' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT
>   INTO `catalog_product_entity_Magento\`
>   (`row_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` =
>   VALUES(`value`)

But this table `catalog_product_entity_Magento\` not exist and have no reason to exist. No occurence in my code use this table. I don't understand what's happening.

Any idea about what's happend and how fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you this :

catalog_product_entity_xx --> the XX stands for the `attribute type`. So if you have an `int` this would result in catalog_product_entity_int.

This is defined in the column `backend_type` in the `eav_attribute` table.
So you can search there for the row with the value `Magento\` in that column. That row is the attribute that causes this error. From there you can find the origin. Propably a badly coded `InstallData` or `UpgradeData` class in a module.

To fix this long term you will need to edit the code to the right backend type. To fix this short term you can edit the column there to `int or datetime or decimal or gallery or text or varchar`

Comment: Oh ! You find it ! Thank you so much ! Perhaps a bad copy/paste in my db, but you save my day ;)

Comment: No problem :D Happy to help!